# tkinter listbox double click convert to user input python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, listboxitem

I have these two functions that should do the same thing, one includes GUI and the other it's just console based :

Console Based:

```
global firstword

def two_x_words():
    init_find_freq()
    firstword = input('Please type word from list:  ')
    print('FirstWord is: ' + firstword)
    find_freq_words(firstword, secondword, thirdword, forthword)
    secondWord = input('Please type word from list:  ')
    print('SecondWord  is: ' + secondWord)
    print(firstword,secondword)
```

GUI Based:

```
global firstword

def get_word(e):
    firstword = my_listbox1.get(ANCHOR)
    return firstword

def two_x_words():
    init_find_freq()
    firstword = my_listbox1.bind('<Double-Button>', get_word)
    print(firstword)
    find_freq_words(firstword, secondword, thirdword, forthword)
    print(secondword)
    print(firstword,secondword)
```

Console version executes code line by line because of the `input('Please type word from list:  ')`

My problem is that in GUI Based, `print(firstword)` executes before the user double clicks a word from listbox.

How can I somehow simulate `input('Please type word from list:  ')`  for when user double clicks in the GUI version ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want `print(firstword)` to occur when the call to `get_word()` returns, in which case you should put it inside *that* function instead of inside `two_x_words()`, since the call to `get_word()` only happens on a double-click event anyway.

You also don't need `global firstword` here because you can keep all instances of `firstword` within a single function. That said, I don't know if you're using `firstword` elsewhere in your code since this example is incomplete.

I should also point out that the event binding in `two_x_words()` won't occur until that function is called somewhere else, but I expect you already know that.

Honestly, as far as the code provided is concerned, you don't need to declare `firstword` at all (see below)

```
def get_word(e):  # this only gets called when the event is fired
    print(my_listbox1.get(ANCHOR))


def two_x_words():
    init_find_freq()  # I'm not sure what this is doing, but I left it in
    my_listbox1.bind('<Double-Button>', get_word)
```

Comment: This works, yes! But it's not really suitable because I need the value of firstword inside two_x_words() because after it will print(firstword) next line is calling a function find_freq_words(firstword, secondword, thirdword, forthword). Right now if i insert this inside two_x_words() it wont work, because firstrword has no value

Comment: find_freq_words(firstword, secondword, thirdword, forthword)  this will look for next frequent words  based on the value of firstword

Comment: @madacmjtr Please edit your question to include the rest of the relevant code and then I can try to help

Comment: Code is updated.  Basically I try to find a replacement for ```firstword = input('Please type word from list:  ')```  in the GUI by assigning value of the Double Click to each variable at a time, so this function would work just as it works in Console Based version

Comment: @madacmjtr I'll need to see what's going on in the ```init_find_freq() ``` and ```find_freq_words()``` functions if you want any more help. I can't figure out what you're trying to do without seeing the whole picture.

Comment: init_find_freq()  outputs a list of most common words from which user picks one, than find_freq_words() looks and outputs a list of next frequent words based on firstword

Comment: @madacmjtr Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Post your code.